# Discrepancy in C++ constructor destructor execution order

Tags: c++, destructor

I understand that the order of calling the destructor is in the reverse order of creation of the objects.

However in the following code I don't understand why the destructor for C(1) and C(2) get called immediately after their constructor.

Also what is the difference between statements: C(2) and C c3(3). The second one is an object initialized with value 3. What is the interpretation of C(2)?

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
public:
  C(int i)
  {   j = i;
      std::cout << "constructor called for "<<j << std::endl;;
    }
  ~C()
  { std::cout << "destructor called for "<<j<< std::endl;; }

private:
  int j;
};

int main() {
  C(1);
  C(2);

  C c3(3);
  C c4(4);
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
constructor called for 1
destructor called for 1
constructor called for 2
destructor called for 2
constructor called for 3
constructor called for 4
destructor called for 4
destructor called for 3
```

Comment: You're creating temporary objects in `main`.  Why wouldn't you expect them to be destroyed right away?

Comment: `C(1);` creates a temporary that is created and destructed on this line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`C(1);` is a statement containing an expression that creates a temporary of type `C`, constructed from the argument `1`.  The temporary is not named - there is no variable name, and no way to refer to that object after the statement finishes executing - so the temporary object's destructor runs immediately after the statement.

That contrasts with `C c3(3);`, which is a variable definition for the variable named `c3`.  It remains in scope until the end of the enclosing scope, which in this case is the function scope.  Because of that, the `c4` constructor and destructor run before `c3`'s destructor.